# Is the dictionary order topology on RxR countable?

Tags: general-topology

I ask because my professor said something along the line of "as each open set contains an uncountable number of real lines, there can be no countable basis". But the set $B=\{(x,y)|x,y\in \mathbb{Q}^2\}$, where $(x,y)$ refers to the open interval $(x,y)=\{z|x<_D z<_D y,z\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ with $<_D$ the dictionary order, seems to be a basis and bijective to $\mathbb{Q}^4$, hence countable.

Maybe I'm just not getting something here.

Comment: For any space $X$ the weight $w(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that $X$ has a base (basis)  of cardinal $k$ or less. The density $d(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k'$ such that $X$ has a dense subset of cardinal $k'$ or less. The cellularity $c(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k''$  such that every discrete open family (a family of pair-wise disjoint open subsets of $X$ ) has cardinal at   $most $   $k''.$....  It is easily shown that $c(X)\leq d(X)\leq w(X).$  So if $X$ has an  uncountable discrete open family then $X$ cannot have a countable base.

Comment: The "or less" conditions in my previous comment are only applicable if $X$ has a finite base or if $X$ has a finite dense subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed basis is insufficient, at the very least since there are open sets in the dictionary order topology all of whose points have (the same) irrational $x$-coordinate.

As an example, the open interval $((\pi, 0), (\pi, 1))$ is given by points of the form $(\pi, y)$ for $y\in (0,1)$.  Any element of $B$ containing a point in the given set will necessarily contain points outside this interval (since all elements of $B$ contain points with rational $x$-coordinates).

Comment: I see, so $B$ is a basis, but it is clear that it isn't the basis for the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, as there is an open set which in not the union or finite intersection of elements of $B$.

Thank you.